# authentication error while importing from netbeans to subversion

Tags: svn, integration, netbeans6.8, collabnet

I just began looking into source control.... And installed subversion from collabnet...
I also use netbeans(6.8) to work with PHP...

I have done the following steps

1. I have installed subversion is c:\program files\collabnet\ and the root for the repositories in e:\svn_repository
2. I then created a repository as e:\svn_repository\lemon
3. I then edited the passwd file and added the user and password
4. I then tried importing an existing project into the repository with the address - svn://localhost/lemon with the new user and password.

   After all this, i get the error "authentication failed"... I am pretty sure the authentication is correct...

I tried importing the project with the address file:///E:/sv_repository/lemon with no authentication and it connected...

But i got other guys who got to connect to this server through lan and svn:// protocol is the only option....

What am i doing wrong here..?
Also.. where can i find a proper tutorial to connect netbeans and collabnet subversion.....?

Thanks for your suggestions and time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the mistake... i had enabled both anon-access and auth-access at the same time in the svnserve.conf file....

Commenting one of them did the trick....

A stupid mistake... but a pitfall to watch for n00bs like me...!!

Cheers..!

Comment: same problem but i just uncommetn the line `### Uncomment the line below to use the default password file.
password-db = passwd` and every thing is commented in svnserve.conf

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart `svnserve` after changing `svnserve.conf`? Are you sure you have added users to `passwd`, not to `svnserve.conf`?

Comment: Oh.. Sorry... I meant passwd.... not svnserve.conf... Also, i have left one of the default accounts as it is.. i tried connecting through it.. still no dice..!!

Comment: Does the client ask for username and password when you connect?

Comment: I am using netbeans to connect to the repo and yes it does ask for authentication but only when i connect through svn:// protocol...

Comment: You can try commandline svn client, though I doubt there will be differences. Double-check that you have a correct path to passwd in `password-db=`, if you've changed that, and that you don't have `auth-access=none`.

Comment: I have checked the items that u have mentioned and they are both ok... still getting the error...

Answer (score -1):

you must setup webdav_svn

Comment: webdav is for http/https access schemes.